# What causes different icons to appear on different monitors in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

We have customers reporting an issue with icons not appearing correctly in Windows 10. I am not able to reproduce the issue with our application, but it is similar in appearance to something that's happening with other programs on my computer. The first screenshot below is from a single computer. It is my task bar on my left and middle monitors. Notice that the "notepad++" icon on the left (it's the highlighted/active icon) is the original icon with the little chameleon sitting on a pencil (you will have to zoom in) and the one on the right just shows the text "n++".

Similarly the Sql Developer icon (immediately to the right of N++) also looks different on different monitors (demonstrating that even when the app's not running this is an issue).

In fact, as I was writing up this question I found that there is a difference between two means of getting at the icon resources in notepad++.exe. If I use IconsExtract (third party tool) on the exe I get the "n++" style icon, but if I right click on N++ in the task bar > Choose properties > Click "Change Icon" I get the chameleon on a pencil icon. You can see these two overlaid in the second image.

I can't for the life of me figure out how windows decides which icon to put where. ***I would be satisfied with a response that just told me where the two different n++ icons really are***.

***What it looks like on my monitors***
[image: What it looks like on my monitors]

***Comparing the two methods of seeing icons***

(Don't be fooled by the second chameleon which does appear to be the same.

[image: Comparing the two methods of seeing icons]

Answer (score 0):

I showed this to a coworker today and he knew the answer... the taskbar on the left was my laptop and I have configured the "size of text, apps, and other items" under "scale and layout" in the "display settings" for that screen to 150%. Changing the size to 100% caused the icons to become the same across all taskbars. I'm still looking for a good article with the details as to *why*, but changing the size definitely fixes the issue.